# Perform random non-repetitive matching in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, google-sheets

I have a list of names out of which I intend to create a pairing/matching system that is non-repetitive.

I'm attaching a Google Sheets link explaining the input and the expected output. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U-hGoOhZbOUbhvKLD7VMLuKjqSL73a62Y51zvAe8wK0/edit?usp=sharing

Here's what I have tried -

Assuming `l1` is a list of names

```
l2 = l1[:(len(l1)//2)]
random.shuffle(l2)
l3 = l1[(len(l1)//2):]
random.shuffle(l3)
combinations = []
final = []
choices = []
x1 = []
x2 = []
for i in l2:
    a = str(random.choice(l3))
    if a not in choices:
        choices.append(a)
    else:
        a = str(random.choice(l3))
    if a != str(i):
        c1 = a + '_' + str(i)
        c2 = str(i) + '_' + a
        if (c1 not in combinations) and (c2 not in combinations):
            combinations.append(c1)
            combinations.append(c2)
            final.append(c2)
            x1.append(str(i))
            x2.append(a)
```

x1 and x2 are my outputs similar to **Team1** and **Team2** in Google Sheets. The solution is appreciated either in Python or in Google Sheets whichever is more optimal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for? The GSheet example makes it look like you are just trying to sort 1 list of names into 2 different teams. Is that all? Not sure where the `combinations`, `final`, & `choices` fit into this?

Comment: Hey @Matty, code might be a little confusing because I'm just starting out. 'combinations' is to record the pairing so I don't get duplicates [N1-N5 and N5-N1 are dupes]. In GSheet, I just provided the actual results I was looking for. For a given list of names, how can I create a pairing/matching that does not repeat. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will do what you want? It ensures each name in the list is against the other only once.

```py
names = ["N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6"]
result = []
count = 1
for i in range(len(names)):
    x = 0 + count
    while x < len(names):
        result.append((names[i], names[x]))
        x += 1
    count += 1
[print(i) for i in result]
```

This will output:

```
('N1', 'N2')
('N1', 'N3')
('N1', 'N4')
('N1', 'N5')
('N1', 'N6')
('N2', 'N3')
('N2', 'N4')
('N2', 'N5')
('N2', 'N6')
('N3', 'N4')
('N3', 'N5')
('N3', 'N6')
('N4', 'N5')
('N4', 'N6')
('N5', 'N6')
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution, Matty! But unfortunately this is not the solution I was looking. Suggest taking another look at the expected output in the GSheet attached. If more explanation is needed, I'll be happy to drop an email to you. Please specify the email address.